# Get list of envelopes for a particular recipient in docusign

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

In my DocuSign application I want to get list of envelopes for specific recipient using email id or user id. Which API endpoint should I use to get list of envelopes for a specific recipient.

I have used below API endpoint
[https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{account_id}/envelopes?from_date=2024-03-01&status=sent&user_id={recipient_user_id}](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7Baccount_id%7D/envelopes?from_date=2024-03-01&status=sent&user_id=%7Brecipient_user_id%7D)

But I am getting below response

{
"resultSetSize": "0",
"totalSetSize": "0",
"nextUri": "",
"previousUri": ""
}

Answer (score 0):

The user_id parameter is for the sender of the envelope, not the recipient.

Change it to `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{account_id}/envelopes?from_date=2024-03-01&status=sent&search_text={recipient_user_id}`

You can get more information as well as try this endpoint by going to:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/

Comment: Anagha, I'm glad I can assist, if this is a good answer - please mark it, thank you!